# Essential singularities in an Alexandrov space

Tags: alexandrov-geometry

For a finitely-dimensional Alexandrov space $X$ with curvature bounded below, a point $p \in X$ is called an essential singular point if $\Sigma_p$ satisfies $\min_{\xi \in\Sigma_p } \max_{\eta \in \Sigma_p}     \angle( \xi, \eta) \le \pi/2$.

Can we prove that the set of essential singular points is closed?